# Impersonate a user when I'm already impersonating another user?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to be able to impersonate a user in my app, so I followed the [tutorial from the website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#impersonating-a-user)

If I try to change my user from user "A" to user "B", it works, but if I try to change to user "C" while I'm already impersonating user "B", the `attemptSwitchUser` method throws this excepcion:

```
You are already switched to "B" user.
500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
```

This is because this method checks wether the current user name (B) equals the user name we want to impersonate (C)

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
$originalToken = $this->getOriginalToken($token);

if (false !== $originalToken) {
    if ($token->getUsername() === $request->get($this->usernameParameter)) {
        return $token;
    } else {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('You are already switched to "%s" user.', $token->getUsername()));
    }
}
```

But obviously this can't never be the case, so I don't know if this is a bug in Symfony's code or if there's something else I'm missing.

Is this really a bug? Can I achieve this functionality without commenting out this block of code?

Comment: maybe you just cut/paste a wrong link that will lead you to an action that tries to impersonate "user B" when you're already "user B"

Comment: No, that's not the case, DonCallisto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Switched user cannot switch to other](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Tests/Functional/SwitchUserTest.php#L32). Before you can do that you need to switch back to the original user ( `?_switch_user=_exit` )

Comment: Oh, I see. But... why would they prevent such a thing? I can't think of any valid reason. I suppose it must be because of security, but why exactly?