# Log out of a switched user programmatically

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an application where the administrator often acts on behalf of the regular users. The flow is as follows:

- Admin logs on
- Admin is presented with a list of non-admin users
- Admin clicks a link to a non-admin user `<a href="{{ path('_main_app', {'_switch_user': user.username}) }}">`
- Admin does their thing as the user
- Admin clicks browser back until they are at the list of non-admin users again

At this point the admin page shows a button `<a href="{{ path('_admin', {'_switch_user': '_exit'}) }}">Exit {{app.user.username}} </a>`

However, the admin users often forget to click it and instead click on another non-admin user. When they do this they get a message [You are already switched to User XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664105/impersonate-a-user-when-im-already-impersonating-another-user). Obviously this is intended, but it is still not a great experience for the admin users.

What would be the recommended approach for allowing the admins to switch users in this way? I would think that calling `{'_switch_user': '_exit'}` every time they reach the list of normal users would be good option (along with forcing this page never to be cached), but I can’t see a way to do that programmatically.

Another way might be to visit the URL `{'_switch_user': '_exit'}` in Javascript, but that seems very unsatisfactory.

What would the recommended approach be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the SwitchUserListener Class (Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener).

This is where the magic happens (and the "you are already switched to... message is created"). The problem is it doesn't give you really that much options to hook into it. Actually the only official one is the event after a successful switch.

But you are able to replace this Listener completely with your own implementation. 
Used that in my own project to implement ip restrictions for a user switch (acls didn't work or i got it wrong)

Simply create your own and replace it in your services.yml

```
security.authentication.switchuser_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Services\Security\SwitchUserListener
    public: false
    abstract: true
    arguments: ['@security.token_storage', '', '@security.user_checker', '', '@security.access.decision_manager', '@?logger', '_switch_user', 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH', '@?event_dispatcher']
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: security }
```

Edit: You will need to copy the whole thing though since all the relevant functions are private. It's not pretty but i don't see any other way (except in your usecase maybe don't show the switch-link at all while the user is already switched.)

Comment: Thanks @Joe, this looks like a good approach. I don't have a `services.yml` file tho? I tried adding this config into my `config.yml` and `security.yml` files, but both throw errors: `FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "app/config/config.yml" from "<snip>config_dev.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security.authentication.switchuser_listener" (in <snip>config.yml). Looked for namespace "security.authentication.switchuser_listener", found  "security", <snip> "fos_user", <snip>)`

Comment: If you don't have a services.yml in your Bundle you can just create one under bundleName/Resources/config/services.yml. Alternatively there should be at least the default one (given a clean sf2 installation) at DocRoot/app/config/services.yml which could be used. Take alook at http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html to dive a little bit deeper into the DI Container topic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a response to not be cached, you can do this on the controller level.
You can render a private response as follow:

```
$expire = new \DateTime('now');
$expire->sub(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));
$response = new Response();
$response->setPrivate();
$response->setExpires($expire);
$response->headers->add(array('Pragma' => 'no-cache'));
```

And then rendering your view with render method in your controller, yan can pass as third parameter you private response

Comment: hi @jeremy, thanks for this. this is really useful to know. my main question was really around forcing a log out a switched user programatically though.

Answer (score 0):

As Joe stated, Symfony's [SwitchUserListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SwitchUserListener.php) especially [SwitchUserListener::attemptExitUser](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SwitchUserListener.php#L159) has all the information you need to programatically logout an impersonated user.

Here's the gist of it (to be used inside a controller):

```
$authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN')) {
    // Code from Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener
    $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');

    $originalToken = false;
    if ($currentToken = $tokenStorage->getToken()) {
        foreach ($currentToken->getRoles() as $role) {
            if ($role instanceof SwitchUserRole) {
                $originalToken = $role->getSource();

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($currentToken === null || $originalToken === false) {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException('Could not find original Token object.');
    }

    if ($this->has('event_dispatcher') && $originalToken->getUser() instanceof UserInterface) {
        $eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        // Attention: Put your user provider here. I wasn't able to find a way to
        //            get the current firewall's user provider programatically.
        $userProvider = $this->get('my.user_provider');

        $originalUser = $userProvider->refreshUser($originalToken->getUser());
        $switchEvent  = new SwitchUserEvent($request, $originalUser);
        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::SWITCH_USER, $switchEvent);
    }

    $tokenStorage->setToken($originalToken);

    // Redirect to the current action so that the request's user is the original one.
    return $this->redirect($request->getRequestUri());
}
```

---

Please note:

- This is tested in **Symfony 2.8** but it shouldn't differ that much for 3.x and even 4.x
- You have to replace `$this->get('my.user_provider')` with the user provider of your firewall. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way to get the current firewall's user programatically.